# When I execute html contaning object/iframe tag to load SVG img without server it shows img but when I run webpage from server it downloads svg img

Tags: html, visual-studio, svg

What is proper way to load svg file in server/client model

> When I execute html contaning object/iframe tag to load SVG img without server it shows img but when I run webpage from server it downloads svg img

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <object data="xyz.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Configure your web server to respond with the correct mime type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and would like to post it for people who face same situation

Open web.config file in your .net project folder and add mime type as shown below
[Add this tag to web.config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKikt.png)

**NOTE : Dont forget to run your site through IIS server and not via visual studio server**